# Error seting up cron job - 0:bad minute without cause

Tags: cron

I've been trying to setup a cron job to run every week day, at 7 am. However, independently of what I do, the following line always return error

"cronFile":0: bad minute

```
#Test
00 07 * * 1-5 Rscript /data/home/username/applyModel2.R
```

Comment: btw, I tried variations with 0 0 or 0 07 or 00 7, but with the same result

Comment: post the entirety of that cronfile

Comment: Now it's the entirety